# How to prevent Debug.Assert(...) to show a modal dialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, assert

I have a couple of libraries which use `Debug.Assert(...)`. I think that the `Debug.Assert(...)` are fine and I still want them to execute, but I don't want them to block the execution of my application. Ideally, I would only like them to be logged somewhere.

Given that I can't change the code of the libraries (and that I still want to compile in debug and run the assertion), how do I prevent `Debug.Assert(...)` to show a modal dialog?

In addition, I would like to make sure that the main program continues when an `Assert` occurs (same behavior as the Ignore button).

Thanks!

Comment: Funny nobody mentioned it here, but `Debug.Assert()` does not end up in your compiled application (when you deploy it in Release mode). This is strictly a debugging tool and won't affect end users. But as mentioned, if you don't fix the assertions, bad things may happen in your application.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. The problem is that `Debug.Assert` is only supposed to be fired *when you have bugs in your code*. If you just ignore them or don't fix them, then you are doing your users a disservice. If, on the other hand, you're firing `Debug.Assert` for things that *aren't* bugs, then you're also doing your users a disservice (by reducing the impact of Debug.Assert).

Having said that, you *can* disable it. The first thing you need to do is remove the default listener from the [Debug.Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) collection:

```
Debug.Listeners.Clear();
```

Then, add your own instead:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(new MyTraceListener());
```

You need to create a class that inherits from [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    // ...

    public override void Fail(string msg, string detailedMsg)
    {
        // log the message (don't display a MessageBox)
    }
}
```

The important method is the [TraceListener.Fail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.fail%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method, which in the implementation of `DefaultTraceListener` is what displays the message box.

Comment: This works perfectly, but when an assertion fail the code doesn't continue to run. I want it to continue. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Martin The point of assertations is to fire when there ARE bugs. If an assertation gets fired, the execution is supposed to stop because the outcome is not predictable. You're trying to abuse assertations and should stick to your own logger.

Comment: We have a scenario where there's a massive legacy code base littered with asserts that are correctly and incorrectly used.  When you want to debug your particular piece of code you have to fight your way through sometimes 100s of asserts to get to your code.  We're slowly cleaning up asserts but in our case it's a valid interim fix to partially disable asserts so this is a valuable answer

Comment: Maybe OP wants an assertion that just triggers in debug and doesn't open an annoying GUI window but just lets the application handle the exception/logging?

Answer (score 31):

There is no need  for `Debug.Listeners.Clear()`

Just add to your *.config*:

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <assert assertuienabled="false"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: This helped me. We want debug insert in some tools, not in others using the same shared dlls.... 
Perfect, just alter app config.

Comment: how to disable in .NET Core web api

Answer (score 5):

Codekas answer is correct, if you want to hit things with a really big hammer.  You can use the `<assert>` element in your application configuration file to set assertuienabled property to false and optionally give a log file for Asserts to be written to.  Then you won't have to write your own listener.

You can read more about the assert element at its [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty5e4c4h.aspx).

Comment: This works perfectly, but when an assertion fail the code doesn't continue to run. I want it to continue. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Martin Pretty old topic here, but why do you want to continue, if you have bugs in your code? I mean, what is your expectation of a wrong result, because any of your assumptions is false?

Comment: @ChristianSt. You're assuming the asserts were correctly used in the first place or you care about everyone else's asserts.  What if you want to just glide through the app until you hit your own break point