# Autofac - What version to use for ASP.NET MVC 1 and examples?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

What Autofac version should I use for ASP.NET MVC 1.0. Also, What examples are available for using it with ASP.NET MVC using the repository pattern?

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUser _user;
    private readonly ICompany _company;

    public MyController(IUser user, ICompany company)
    {
        _user = user;
        _company = company;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Actions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use `StructureMap` for my application. Here's what I've did to make it work:

Create my own CustomFactory class:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(controllerType);
        }

        try
        {
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
        }
        catch (StructureMapException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a Bootstrapper, using the StructureMap convention to register all the interfaces and its implementation for my assembly. (I've posted a [blog post](http://www.kennysax.com/Blog#postTitle=2011-05-12-structuremap-with-asp-net-mvc1) on this):

```
public class StructureMapBootstrapper : IBootstrapper
{
    private static bool hasStarted;

    public void BootstrapStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<FactoryRegistry>();
        });
    }

    public static void Restart()
    {
        if (hasStarted)
        {
            ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults();
        }
        else
        {
            Bootstrap();
            hasStarted = true;
        }
    }

    public static void Bootstrap()
    {
        new StructureMapBootstrapper().BootstrapStructureMap();
    }
}

public class FactoryRegistry : Registry
{
    public FactoryRegistry()
    {
        Scan(s =>
        {
            s.Assembly("Calendar.Library");
            s.TheCallingAssembly();
            s.AddAllTypesOf<IController>().NameBy(type => type.Name.Replace("Controller", "").ToLower());
            s.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}
```

Register StructureMap in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    StructureMapBootstrapper.Bootstrap();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use it at all.

According to http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration only MVC2 was supported.

Comment: I was looking at this page right before I posted my question here and was hoping that someone would point me to the right version. Too bad it's not supported. How about StructureMap, does it supports ASP.NET MVC 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autofac 1.4.1 through 1.4.4 for ASP.NET MVC1. I'm running 1.4.2. Here's a sample bootstrapper for Autofac 1.4.2 (with a few snippets removed. not sure what changed in 1.4.4 that might affect this code).

```
namespace Web
{
    public class PropertyInjectionForAllComponents : Module
    {
        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration (IContainer container, IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            registration.Activating += ActivatingHandler.InjectProperties;
        }
    }

    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IContainerProvider ConfigureAutofac (string serverPath)
        {
            var configManager = new ConfigManager (new ConfigurationManagerWrapper ());

            string environment = configManager.AppSettings ("Environment");

            RequireSslAttribute.Enable = configManager.AppSettings ("EnableSSL").IsTrue ();

            // Autofac IoC configuration see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/di-with-autofac.aspx for details
            // ExternallyOwned () - Use on objects that are disposable which you do not want disposed such as Console.Out as an implementation TextWriter.
            // OnActivating () - Allows property injection
            // SingletonScoped () - Only one instance of the class will ever be created for the process. This is the default behavior.
            // FactoryScoped () - Each time a component is requested from the container, a new instance will be created.
            // ContainerScoped () - This provides the flexibility needed to implement per-thread, per-request, or per-transaction component life-cycles.
            // HttpRequestScoped () - Means that at most one instance of the component will be created for each incoming web request. This is handy for items that should be shared within a single request, e.g. repositories.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder ();

            // SCIBS.Core components
            builder.Register (c => new HttpContextWrapper (HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase> ().HttpRequestScoped ();
            builder.Register<ElmahLogger> ().As<ILogger> ().OnActivating (ActivatingHandler.InjectProperties).SingletonScoped ();
            builder.Register<WebConfigurationManagerWrapper> ().WithArguments (new NamedParameter ("applicationVirtualPath", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath)).As<IConfigurationManager> ().SingletonScoped ();
            builder.Register<ConfigManager> ().As<IConfigManager> ().SingletonScoped ();
            builder.Register<AppSettings> ().As<IAppSettings> ().SingletonScoped ();
            builder.Register<SparkTemplate> ().As<ITemplate> ().SingletonScoped ();
            builder.Register<Security> ().As<ISecurity> ().HttpRequestScoped ();
            builder.Register<MailerService> ().WithArguments (new NamedParameter ("mailLogger", new Log4NetLogger ("EmailLogger"))).As<IMailerService> ().FactoryScoped ();

            builder.Register<QuoteService> ().As<IQuoteService> ().FactoryScoped ();
            builder.Register<OrderService> ().As<IOrderService> ().FactoryScoped ();

            builder.Register<AccountRepository> ().As<IAccountRepository> ().FactoryScoped ();

            builder.Register<ContactService> ().As<IContactService> ().FactoryScoped ();
            builder.Register<AccountService> ().As<IAccountService> ().FactoryScoped ();
            builder.Register<AddressService> ().As<IAddressService> ().FactoryScoped ();
            builder.Register<AspNetMembershipProvider> ().As<IMembershipProvider> ().FactoryScoped ();

            var autofacControllerModule = new AutofacControllerModule (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ());
            autofacControllerModule.ActivatingHandler += ActivatingHandler.InjectProperties;
            builder.RegisterModule (autofacControllerModule);

            builder.RegisterModule (new PropertyInjectionForAllComponents ());

            IContainerProvider containerProvider = new ContainerProvider (builder.Build ());
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory (new AutofacControllerFactory (containerProvider));

            return containerProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

And how it's called from your application:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
    private static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

    public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return _containerProvider;
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start ()
    {
        Log.Info ("Application_Start");

        string serverPath = Server.MapPath ("~");
        _containerProvider = Bootstrapper.ConfigureAutofac (serverPath);

        var configManager = ContainerProvider.RequestContainer.Resolve<IConfigManager> ();
        EnableSSL = configManager.AppSettings ("EnableSSL").IsTrue ();

        RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes);

        // NOTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854024/how-to-prevent-debug-assert-to-show-a-modal-dialog
        var logger = ContainerProvider.RequestContainer.Resolve<ILogger> ();
        Debug.Listeners.Clear ();
        Debug.Listeners.Add (new LoggerTraceListener () {Log = logger});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Todd, is there a way for Autofac to automatically register the Repositories/Interfaces automatically, or we have to do it manually for each individual ones? StructureMap have a convention where it can scan the assembly and register all the components needed. Thanks.

Comment: The call to AutofacControllerModule does that for you. Just give it a different assembly reference.