# Redirect Debug.Assert() output

Tags: c#, debugging

I'd like to let my application redirect all Debug and Trace outputs to a file and Console.Out when a parameter is supplied from the command line.
For normal `Debug.WriteLine()` messages, this one works already:

```
TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] {
                new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out),
                new TextWriterTraceListener(debugFile),
            };
            Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);
```

But it doesn't for `Debug.Assert(condition, "message")`.

How can I redirect the output from `Debug.Assert()` like I did with the `Debug.WriteLine()` output?

Edit:

I've added a subclass of TextWriterTraceListener in order to send assertion-failed-messages to the console or a debug file:

```
// used to redirect assert debug messages
private class AssertTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public AssertTraceListener(TextWriter w) : base(w) {}
    public AssertTraceListener(String s) : base(s) {}

    public override void Fail(string message)
    {
        // uncomment if you want the modal dialog
        //base.Fail(message);
        WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

I call them like this now:

```
    TextWriterTraceListener[] twlisteners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] {
        new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out),
        new TextWriterTraceListener(debugFile)
    };
    AssertTraceListener[] listeners = new AssertTraceListener[] {
        new AssertTraceListener(Console.Out),
        new AssertTraceListener(debugFile)
    };
    Debug.Listeners.Clear();
    Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);
    Debug.Listeners.AddRange(twlisteners);
```

`debugFile` contains a valid path but none of my messages (neither Debug.WriteLine messages nor assert messages) go to my debugFile. What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854024/how-to-prevent-debug-assert-to-show-a-modal-dialog

Comment: @VladimirFrolov I've edited my question now. I know, my first version looked like a duplicate, but I think it's now a bit more specialized and deserves to be left open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself now. My problem was, that one of my custom TraceListeners won't write the Messages to the file I passed to it in the ctor.

This is my code now:

```
private class AssertTextWriterTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public AssertTextWriterTraceListener(TextWriter w) : base(w) {}
    public AssertTextWriterTraceListener(String s) : base(s) {}

    public override void Fail(string message)
    {
        // uncomment if you want the modal dialog
        //base.Fail(message);
        WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Note, that I commented out the call to `base.Fail(message)`. If the call gets passed into the base class, a modal dialog will pop up on a failed assertion offering the 3 options abort, retry and ignore.

The code in my main method looks like this:

```
    AssertTextWriterTraceListener fileTL = new AssertTextWriterTraceListener(debugFile);
    AssertTextWriterTraceListener consoleTL = new AssertTextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true; // necessary to get the Debug-Messages flushed to the debugFile
    // clearing the default listener and adding the custom ones.
    Debug.Listeners.Clear();
    Debug.Listeners.Add(fileTL);
    Debug.Listeners.Add(consoleTL);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress the assertion dialog then you will need to clear out the existing debug listeners as the `DefaultTraceListener` is responsible for that.

Then, add your own implementation of `TraceListener` and override the `Fail` methods, along with the `TextWriterTraceListener` implementations you show in your question.

For convenience, just subclass `DefaultTraceListener` and override the `Fail` methods in such a way that the base implementations are not invoked.

Comment: what do I have to do in order to let the Listener accept TextWriters or FileNames in its ctor and write the assert messages to them? I've just subclassed TextWriterTraceListener, created two ctors for either of the input types and added a simple WriteLine-statement in the Fail(string) method which should call the WriteLine method in the baseclass, right? (I'll add my code to my question)

Comment: @wullxz, which listener are you wanting to pass a TextWriter to? If it's your own implementation, what's stopping you adding the necessary constructor? If you attach a breakpoint in your implementation, is it being hit as you would expect?

Comment: I've added them both, as you can see in my question (edited yesterday). I'd like to pass it to my own derived class `AssertTraceListener`.