# Debug.Assert popup in design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, assert

Is it possible to suppress the popup of assertion while in design time (XAML Editor)?

We have removed code contracts from our project and replaced them with debug assertion for sanity check. Now we got huge trouble with the XAML-Designer as the assertions create a popup even in design time.

I thought i got a solution for this but it didn't help. We got a own base window class and every window inherits so i thought

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    Debug.Listeners.Clear();
}
```

inside of the constructor would help, but unfortunatly it didn't.

Comment: You might fix it by wrapping the asserts with this if-condition. I don't think the Designer listens but simply executes your code.

Comment: The problem is that this is not possible as there are assertions failing that got no access to a dependency object, and that for a good reason ;-)

Comment: So you want the assertions but not the message box?

Comment: I want to suppress the messagebox while i am in design time.

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854024/how-to-prevent-debug-assert-to-show-a-modal-dialog

Comment: Yes, i already found that. But general deactivation is no option, as the assertions have their rights to exists. We do need them for sanity checks.

Comment: When a control is used in a designer you are using the control as if it was a finished product. A finished product should not contain Asserts. Chances are that the asserts should be proper exceptions instead. Asserts are for the developer of the component, not for the developer of the user of the component.

Comment: you do know that Debug.Assert is ignored by roslyn on release builds? so i do not understand that statement.

Comment: Yes, and that exactly proves my point. After releasing, when you use the component there should be no asserts. So, create a release build and use that in the designer. (I won't continue this here because this is turning into a discussion which does not answer your actual question but I thought this might be relevant as I expect no answer that will show you how to disable it)